# Opening a tmproj file in TextMate

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, textmate

I downloaded the most recent version of TextMate and now can't seem to open a `.tmproj` file I was using as recently as a year and a half ago. (I don't remember the age of my previous copy of TextMate as it was on a computer I no longer have - sorry!) I feel like I might be missing something painfully obvious here. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using TextMate 2 now? Project files are gone and won't come back (at least not in the older / original appearance).

TextMate 2 now remembers your opened projects / directories, e.g opened via `mate .`. A couple of weeks ago, a new feature was added: If you press ⌘⇧-O, you can browse recent projects in a ⌘-T like manner.

For project specific configuration, we now have .tm_properties files per directory. See http://blog.macromates.com/2011/git-style-configuration/ for a quick introduction. There are a couple of other blog posts and tips about these configuration files out there, you will find them.